# user defined months added to given date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to add a user defined amount of months to the date previously added. $CustDate is already in YYYY-MM-DD format from previous form.

```
$CustDate=$_POST['formYear'] . "-" . $_POST['formMonth'] . "-" . $_POST['formDay'];

$months=$_POST['formMonthsAdded'];
$d=strtotime("+" . $months . " Months");

$CustAddedDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($CustDate, $d));
```

If I enter the date as: 2016-08-04 as the $CustDate, it gives me the same value for the $CustAddedDate.

Where am I screwing this up? Thanks!

Comment: `$d` in there is not used for anything, since your `$CustDate` doesn't contain any "relative" values. it's all absolute year/month/day. the 2nd arg for strtotime() sets a base time for things like `strtotime('+1 day', $some_point_in_time)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the `+ months` along with the `$CustDate`. Provide the `$Cusdate` as the second argument in the addition.

```
$CustAddedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+" . $months . " Months", strtotime($CustDate)));
                                                                  // ^ add this with the addition
```

Or the `DateTime` variant:

```
$date = new DateTime($CustDate);
$date->modify('+ ' . $months . ' Month');
$CustAddedDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $CustAddedDate;
```

Answer (score 2):

Note:

```
$d = strtotime('2016-03-02'); // March 2nd, 2016 -> 1456898400

echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day', $d)); -> 2016-03-03
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2010-01-02', $d)); -> 2010-01-02
```

The second argument for `strtotime()` set a time basis for any "relative" time values, like `+1 day` or `yesterday`. Since you're passing in an absolute date, `2016-08-04`, there's no "relative" measure to base anything on, and your absolute date is used in its entirety for the conversion.

If you want to adjust that absolute date, you have to do something like

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2016-08-04 + 1 day')) -> 2016-08-05
```

e.g. embed the date math into the string you're passing into `strtotime`, and not in the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
$CustDate=$_POST['formYear'] . "-" . $_POST['formMonth'] . "-" . $_POST['formDay'];

$months=$_POST['formMonthsAdded'];

$d="+" . $months . " Months"; //not strtotime time here!

$CustAddedDate=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($d,strtotime($CustDate)));//watch the order of arguments and missing strtotime of the existing date
```